# How to apply vlookups to a range of cells dynamically within a single cell?

Tags: excel, sum, formula, vlookup

I'm trying to sum numbers which are the result of multiple vlookups in a single cell.
Is there a way to do this dynamically? and more efficiently than I have done now?

MY current formula below is looking up values in from Cells A7 to A18. Cells from B7 to B18 just contain a tick-mark to show if that attribute is there today or not. This formula is sitting in cell B6. Each attribute from rows A7 to A18 has a value attributed against it. That value is on a data sheet in the spreadsheet out of sight. This formula is supposed to check if cells B7 to B18 are not blank, if they are not blank it will lookup the value in the data sheet associated to the attribute in column A sum up all values which are not blank to give me one value within the cell which changes according to how many attributes are not blank.

=SUM(IF(B7<>"",VLOOKUP($A$7,'Data Sheet'!$E$1:$F$8,2,0),0),IF(B8<>"",VLOOKUP($A$8,'Data Sheet'!$E$1:$F$8,2,0),0),IF(B9<>"",VLOOKUP($A$9,'Data Sheet'!$E$1:$F$8,2,0),0),IF(B10<>"",VLOOKUP($A$10,'Data Sheet'!$E$1:$F$8,2,0),0),IF(B11<>"",VLOOKUP($A$11,'Data Sheet'!$E$1:$F$8,2,0),0),IF(B12<>"",VLOOKUP($A$12,'Data Sheet'!$E$1:$F$8,2,0),0),IF(B13<>"",VLOOKUP($A$13,'Data Sheet'!$H$1:$I$7,2,0),0),IF(B14<>"",VLOOKUP($A$14,'Data Sheet'!$H$1:$I$7,2,0),0),IF(B15<>"",VLOOKUP($A$15,'Data Sheet'!$H$1:$I$7,2,0),0),IF(B16<>"",VLOOKUP($A$16,'Data Sheet'!$H$1:$I$7,2,0),0),IF(B17<>"",VLOOKUP($A$17,'Data Sheet'!$H$1:$I$7,2,0),0),IF(B18<>"",VLOOKUP($A$18,'Data Sheet'!$H$1:$I$7,2,0),0),-5)

MY question is, is there a more efficient formula or method for me to do this? if I have another attribute in row A19 for example this will result in me to change my formula by adding another if statement.

Is there way to apply this logic in a better way?

Thanks

Comment: If you are on Microsoft 365 then `FILTER()` may a good choice. Please post few sample data and desired output and mention you version of excel.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output